# Any way to perform Delta-import in XPathEntityProcessor?

Tags: solr, delta-index

**As per SOLR documentation:**

The only EntityProcessor which supports delta-import is SqlEntityProcessor!

The XPathEntityProcessor has not implemented it yet. So, unfortunately, there is no delta support for XML at this time

Any one has tried implementing delta-import with XPathEntityProcessor successfully by any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following URL:

It might resolve your problem....

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Store-complete-XML-record-DIH-amp-XPathEntityProcessor-td3205524.html